# Gradle Issue in Intellij

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot gradle project. I have imported it as module into intellij and it was working fine.

But for some reason its started running indefinetly

Comment: can you paste exact codebase you're having problems with? and explain the state of the project before it was imported into intellij

Comment: Codebase is private. The project was running fine for many days.

Its running indefinetely in Execute exec task

Answer (score 0):

Found and killed all the background gradle processes running then things started working fine.